# Advice on a setting up a firewall

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it worth setting up a firewall for my site?

Do you have any recommendation of a good firewall to use?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=csf+firewall

Comment: Is more devop or security oriented.